# Tooltip font too small on 4k display (doesn't scale)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a 15.6" 4K laptop display. I can easily scale up Android Studio and its fonts -- except for tooltip fonts (i.e. starting tips, and when I hover over a word for Javadocs). Is there a setting to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you didn't figure it out already: When the tool-tip appears, there is a configuration button in the upper right corner of the window.  Click it, and you get a slider to set your desired font size.

Comment: Is this solution for the Windows? I have this issue in Windows 10 on my 4k display!

Comment: Yes it is. I am using Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it's might will help. If you choose this selection, you can change font size like Chrome.

[image: CTRL+Mouse wheel scroll]